# Tools to visualize 'the stack' in assembly

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, callstack

Are there any ways to see what values that are pushed onto the stack in a simple, preferably visual way? Currently I'm using `gdb` for debugging, but was wondering if there were any other programs (or possibly even gdb in another mode) to have a view onto what the stack looks like as I step through each instruction, for example in this program:

```
.globl main
main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    movb $8, -1(%rbp)
    movw $30, -4(%rbp)
    mov -1(%rbp), %rax
    add -4(%rbp), %rax
```

I know in gdb there is `x/8xw $rbp` or variations thereof, but I'd like to view this almost like an animation or constant visualization while stepping through code. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `display` to print something every time GDB stops, e.g.

```
display /x (long [8])*(long*)$rsp
```

to get output like this after every step.  (This one from `_start`, so RSP is pointing at `argc` (0x1), then `argv[0]` (a pointer), then `argv[1]` (NULL), then `envp[0]`, etc.)

```
{0x1, 0x7fffffffea02, 0x0, 0x7fffffffea0e, 0x7fffffffea1e, 0x7fffffffea6c, 0x7fffffffea7e, 0x7fffffffea92}
```

The GDB cast expression works by dereferencing `$rsp` (the stack pointer) as a single `long`, then casting that to an array of `long`.  This of course wouldn't actually work in C, but GDB expressions only use C-like syntax, they aren't proper C.  There might be an easier way to write this, but it's what I came up with through trial and error.

This will show qwords in increasing order of memory address, starting with the one RSP points to, so it will change after a `call` or `push`, for example.  If you want to see *below* RSP, into the red zone, use a different base, like `($rsp-16)` or something.

---

If you want a view of your function's stack frame below RBP that doesn't move with push/pop, you might want a base like `($rbp - 16)` or something.

Of course, your `x/8xw $rbp` command doesn't show you any of the memory your instructions store into, because you're storing *below* RBP = RSP.  (That's actually guaranteed safe in the x86-64 System V ABI, which has a red zone.  In many other calling conventions, that could be stepped on asynchronously by a signal handler, or by a debugger evaluating `print foo(1)` where `foo` is a function in your program.)